# Rendering Problems(Artifacts, Flickering) with the Mirage Solo VR Headset

Tags: unity, rendering, virtual-reality

Im getting some strange flickering artifacts when testing on device (Mirage solo), this problem occurs on Unity 2018.3.2 and Unity 2019.1.2. Its not happening on other devices such as the OculusGo, Google Pixel, Samsung s7,s9. It seems to be only occuring on devices that use Qualcomm Adreno 540 GPU. Has anyone else encountered anything like this if so, did you fix it and how? The Environment is using a custom shader, the robot character is simply using a unity standard shader and there is a hologram at the side(right) which is using a custom shader.

**Hardware:** Snapdragon 835 SoC Qualcomm Adreno 540 GPU

**Video:** https://streamable.com/

**Screenshots:**

Bad:
[image: This is what the problem looks like]

Good:
[image: This is what is should look like...every frame!]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with these settings:[image: Fixed]

For reference i remained on 2018.3.2f1, due to separate issues found on 2019. Good luck!